# Recursive program to find the value of x when xˣ = N

Tags: java, function, recursion, math, input

I need to find the value of x when x<sup>x</sup> = N, N is a value inputted. Let's assume N is 27. In this example, the x value would be 3, since the cube root of 27 is 3, or 3<sup>3</sup> = 27. If N is 256 then x would be 4, since 4<sup>4</sup> = 256.

I need to figure out a recursive program that figures out the value of x. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    double number = n.nextDouble();


}

public static void findXValue(double n) {

    double logn = Math.log(n);
...
```

The `findXValue` function uses logs, but it also doesn't work. And I need to use a recursive method as well. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: avoid `x^x` because it has a different meaning in Java and will be very confusing

Comment: You can rewrite the formula as y = xth root(n).  Plug in any value for x and calculate y.  Average the difference between x and y and substitute the average value for x.  Repeat until the difference between x and y < 0.00005 (or whatever tolerance you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Newton's method](https://calcworkshop.com/derivatives/newtons-method/) to approach the root.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class XPowerX {
    static final double PRECISION = 0.00001;
    static final int MAX_RECURSION = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        double number = n.nextDouble();

        System.out.println(findXValue(number));
    }

    public static double findXValue(double n) {
        double seed = Math.random();
        double y = Math.pow(seed, seed);
        double derivative;
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_RECURSION; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(y) <= PRECISION) {
                return seed;
            }

            y = Math.pow(seed, seed);
            derivative = y * Math.log(seed) + y;
            y -= n;
            // The derivative is used as the slope of tangent line

            // Newton's method
            seed = seed - y / derivative;

            if(seed < 0) {
                seed = 0;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number
16
2.7453680235674636

Enter a number
0.8
0.7395336501071896

Enter a number // No real root
0.3
-1.0

Enter a number // Overflow (NaN)
125000
-1.0
```

Comment: For input between about 0.7 to 1, the answer may change depending on the initial guess, because there are 2 roots possible

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static double findXValue(double n) {
        double result = 0.0;
        double number = 0.0;
        while(result <= n) {
            result = Math.pow(number, number);
            if(result == n) {
                return number;
            }

            number++;
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: You're not likely to get an exact match for `result == n`.  Better to check `Math.abs(result - n) < 0.00005` (or some other tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming x can be a floating point number, since you didn't say.

You can look at this as the problem of finding a root of the function F(x) = x<sup>x</sup> - N.  The simplest approach is called bisection, which works something like binary search.

Start with an interval [a, b] such that F(a) and F(b) have opposite signs. For this problem that's always F(a)<0 and F(b)>0 due to the nature of the function.  Here if N > 1, start with [1,N]. If 0 <= N < 1, use [N,1]. (If N = 1, then x = 1).

After that, iterate. Compute x = (a+b)/2.  If F(x) and F(a) have the same sign (negative), then set a=x. Else F(x) must have the same sign as F(b) (positive), so set b=x.

When a and b differ by at most one unit-of-least-precision (smallest floating point difference possible), stop and return a.

This iteration is easy to express as a recursion. I'm not going to give you the answer.

```
double solve(double a, double b, double n) {
  if (b - a <= ULP) return a;

  // all the fun happens here
}
```

The same technique will work for integers, but be careful about overflow and roundoff errors when computing the midpoint.